# Why is shell process named -bash when I configured terminal to use /usr/local/bin/bash?

Tags: terminal

I have the default **Ask before closing** setting on my macOS terminal -- *Only if there are processes other than the login shell and `screen`, `tmux`*.

But even if I open a new terminal window and close it, it asks "Do you want to terminate running processes in this window?  Closing this window will terminate the running process -bash."

Adding `-bash` to the "processes other than" gets rid of that dialog, but why the heck is there a `-bash` process, hyphen and all?  I configured **shells open with** to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, I don't know why that would show as `-bash`.  But it shows up that way in `ps` as well.  `which -- -bash` doesn't find anything.  This seems janky.

This is happening for me on Big Sur, and I'm pretty sure it was happening on Catalina as well.

Comment: Can you [edit] with the contents of your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: I have a `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, not terribly complicated, but I just tried disabling them temporarily (by prefixing with `_`) and I'm still seeing this issue, so I assume there's some other problem?

Comment: this also happens for me